# How to replicate site collections on the same web application?

Tags: site-collection, web-application, backup

I need to create a copy of publishing(Collobaration Portal) site collection on the same web application. I can do this by using backup/restore, but the problem is when we restore the same site collection on the same web application on different url, then we have to create this site collection in a new database, which is completely fine as restore does restore the same GUIDS for lists (Which cannot co-exist in the same Db). I need to make multiple copies of the same site collection on the same web application. Now the question is.. if I am replicating a single site collection so many times on the same web application on different URLs(and also in different Db's), will it be a problem in the future? or can I go ahead and replicate the site collection?

Landing site collection - 
http://extranet

1st Site collection(This site collection will be replicated) - 
http://extanet/sites/site1

2nd site collection(this is a copy of 1st site collection on same web app on different URL) - http://extranet/sites/site2

3rd site collection(this is a copy of 1st site collection on same web app on different URL) - http://extranet/sites/site3

Comment: so, if I understand you correctly, you have found a way to do this already but you are concerned that it may not be a good idea to have that many site collections under a single web application with separate databases?

Answer (score 1):

Beyond understanding why you are wanting to do this, I would recommend trying the SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard on CodePlex.

http://www.codeplex.com/SPDeploymentWizard

Comment: I tried that already, but it doesn't work properly with publishing site collections:-(

Comment: Content Deployment Wizard should work just fine with publishing site collections